# fix for spot bug - HRS_REQUEST_PARAMETER_TO_HTTP_HEADER

Tags: java, http, urlencode, spotbugs

I am executing below code inside servlet and getting this spot bugs - HRS_REQUEST_PARAMETER_TO_HTTP_HEADER
Bug: HTTP parameter directly written to HTTP header output in SSOIdpLogoutRedirect.doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)

```
String relayState = request.getParameter("RELAY_STATE");
if(relayState != null)
{
 response.sendRedirect(relayState);
}
```

To fix this bugs i added below code.

```
relayState = URLEncoder.encode(relayState,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But URL does not redirect in correct way as i can see the relaystate url has been changed after encoding
original relaystate = https://sad.ezhdj.net/system/web/apps/dfgh/
and after encoded it is

relaystate =https%3A%2F%2Fsad.ezdev.net%2Fsystem%2Fweb%2Fapps%2Fdfgh%2F`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `HttpServletResponse.encodeRedirectURL()` to encode redirect urls:

> [String encodeRedirectURL(String url)](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL-java.lang.String-)
>
> Encodes the specified URL for use in the `sendRedirect` method or, if
> encoding is not needed, returns the URL unchanged. The implementation
> of this method includes the logic to determine whether the session ID
> needs to be encoded in the URL.
>
> ...
>
> All URLs sent to the `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect` method should be
> run through this method...

this should work:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(relayState));
```

since your url doesn't actually need encoding, output from `encodeRedirectURL()` will be:

```
https://sad.ezhdj.net/system/web/apps/dfgh/
```

and the redirect will work just fine.

**edit:**

apparently proposed solution still triggers `HRS_REQUEST_PARAMETER_TO_HTTP_HEADER` spotbug error.

after doing little more [research](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bugDescriptions.html#hrs-http-response-splitting-vulnerability-hrs-request-parameter-to-http-header) I found out that the error is meant to prevent [HTTP response splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting) vulnerability (i.e. when unwanted `\r\n` are written in the header section of http response).

we should then *better* sanitize `relayState` against this type of vulnerability.

a simple `relayState.replace("\r\n", "")` is enough to make the error go away:

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(relayState.replace("\r\n", "")));
```

Comment: Thanks !! I already tried it. Spotbugs is also giving bug after this. 
  response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(relayState));

Comment: @ashishgupta oh I'm sorry, that is really unfortunate, I updated my answer